# How to I query this table to pick from the symbol list?

Tags: kdb

I would like to filter out the record that has `1 from the symbol list

Example table:

```
tab:([]a:((``1`2);`a;b);c:1 2 3);
```

I tried this:

```
select from tab where a = `1
```

also this:

```
select from tab where `1 in raze a
```

None of those work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the table:

```
q)tab:([]a:((``1`2);`a;`b);c:1 2 3)
q)tab
a     c
-------
``1`2 1
`a    2
`b    3
```

You could use the keyword `in` combined with [each right](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) to remove the desired row:

```
q)select from tab where not `1 in/: a
a c
---
a 2
b 3
```

Comment: thanks this works! do you know the theory that is behind it for using each right?

Comment: Because `a` is a nested symbol list, you want to check each row in column `a` if it contains 1. `not 1 in/: a` applies `1 in` to each row of a. Effectively does this:
`1 in 1 2`
`1 in a`
`1 in b` 
=
`100b`
Then `not` flips that to return the last 2 rows

Comment: the same could be achieved with each-both since 1 is an atom:
`not 1 in' a`

Answer (score 4):

Hey your tab gives a `'b` error so i've swapped b->3

```
q)tab
a     c
-------
``1`2 1
`a    2
3     3
q)select from tab where max each`1~''a
a    c
------
 1 2 1
q)select from tab where not max each`1~''a
a  c
----
`a 2
3  3
```